# python flask , how to measure CPU of what is running outside the request context and causing high CPU usage?

Tags: python, flask, profiler

i tried profiler  `werkzeug.contrib.profiler import ProfilerMiddleware` to profile , but it shows only  cpu usage for  1 request, and doesnt show cpu usage outside of request context. Actually requests are fast and without problems. But while flask isn't executing any request, it takes 50%+ CPU, just when it's inside flask's while-loop waiting for requests... I guess there must be problem within my app code, because i tried some other flask application and it's CPU was <5%

i uploaded my flask app here: http://www.filedropper.com/flask

Comment: Are you running with debug set to true?  I find that my flask app takes high CPU when not doing anything if I'm running in debug mode but is fine with debug set to false.

Comment: Dave! GENIUS! :) , it was exactly the problem, i had debugggin on , i can accept answer if u make it answer

Comment: yes u were right, i can accept as answer if u want and make it answer